# Find words missing from a Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database containing words from a dictionary. If a query is made using a word not in the dictionary (such as a mis-spelled word), I want the query to return just the missing words.

I can do the opposite. This query returns words from the database that are correctly spelled:

```
MATCH (w:Word)
WHERE w.spelling IN ["good","words","plus","twoo","that","are","mispleled"]
RETURN w.spelling AS word
```

Can I write a query that will return something like ["twoo","mispleled"]? Or do I have to use a query like the one above, and check in the application itself which words have not been matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without `OPTIONAL MATCH`:

```
WITH ["good", "words", "plus", "twoo", "that", "are", "mispleled"] AS words
MATCH (word:Word) WHERE word.spelling IN words
WITH words, COLLECT(word.spelling) AS matched
RETURN [x IN words WHERE NOT x IN matched];
```

The advice about creating an index still applies.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

This might work for you. `{input_words}` is a parameter that contains an array of the words you want to check.

```
UNWIND {input_words} AS in_word
OPTIONAL MATCH (w:Word { spelling: in_word })
RETURN REDUCE(s = [], x IN COLLECT({ w: w, in_word: in_word }) |
  CASE WHEN x.w IS NULL THEN s + x.in_word ELSE s END) AS missing_word;
```

For efficiency, you should first create an index on `:Word(spelling)`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Word(spelling);
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It returns all the input words, regardless of whether they exist or not. However the query `UNWIND ["one","ivnvalid","word"] AS in_word
OPTIONAL MATCH (w:Word {spelling: in_word})
RETURN w` does return `null` only for the mis-spelled word.

Comment: Sorry, fixed my answer.